# Ghostscript 8.57: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1

Tags: ghostscript

I do have a problem in producing a pdf (latex -> dvips -> ps2pdf) with an error saying

```
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1084/1123(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:69/200(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: 2
GPL Ghostscript 8.57: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
```

Comment: How `filename.ps` was generated? What is the *complete* error message of Ghostscript?

Comment: I can not reproduce > dvips -> ps2pdf).

Comment: If already `dvips` fails to generate a PostScript file, then it is not a surprise that Ghostscript throws an error. But a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) would be helpful.

Comment: This latex package I used.I guess there is some hidden files are missing. I could reproduce ps2pdf A.ps----->open A.pdf  documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn,floatfix,superscriptaddress,showpacs]{revtex4}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts,bbm,graphicx,hyperref,times,psfrag}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{color}

Comment: Please add the lines before `Execution stack`, there should be a line starting `Error: ...` and `Operand stack:`. Also you can edit your question to add the *complete* MWE and try to strip down the example file by removing stuff/packages that do not cause the problem.

Comment: interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1084/1123(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:69/200(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: 2
GPL Ghostscript 8.57: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
hermans-macbook-herman~/Documents/AA$ps2pdf A.ps
Error: /undefinedfilename in (A.ps)

Comment: `Error: /undefinedfilename in (A.ps)`: that means, `A.ps` was not generated and does not exist. Thus the previous step (`dvips`) already failed.

Comment: Transcript written on A.log.
herman~/Documents/AA$dvips A.dvi
This is dvips(k) 5.95a Copyright 2005 Radical Eye Software (www.radicaleye.com)
' TeX output 2013.06.15:1522' -> |lpr
<tex.pro><psfrag.pro><8r.enc><texps.pro><special.pro><color.pro>. <cmbx9.pfb>
<cmsy5.pfb><cmr5.pfb><cmmi5.pfb><cmex10.pfb><cmr6.pfb><cmmi6.pfb><cmsy9.pfb>
<cmr9.pfb><cmmi9.pfb><cmr7.pfb><cmsy10.pfb><cmmi7.pfb><cmmi10.pfb><cmr10.pfb>
<cmsy6.pfb><cmsy7.pfb>[1] [2<A.eps>] [3] [4] [5] [6<Fig1.eps><Fig2.eps>] [7
<Fig3.eps><Fig4.eps><Fig5.eps>] [8<Fig6.eps>] [9]

Comment: the A.dvi works fine but ps2pdf failed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `dvips` is configured to send the output to `lpr` (printing) instead of generating a PostScript file. From the output, given in your comment:

`This is dvips(k) 5.95a [...] ' TeX output 2013.06.15:1522'`
**`-> |lpr`** `[...]`

The output PostScript file can be specified directly:

```
dvips -o A.ps A.dvi
```

generates a PostScript file `A.ps` that can then be processed by `ps2pdf`:

```
ps2pdf A.ps
```

`dvips` can be reconfigured via the configuration file `config.ps`. It can be found by `kpsewhich`:

```
kpsewhich config.ps
```

For example it returns `.../texmf-dist/dvips/config/config.ps`.
Then locate the line:

```
o |lpr
```

that pipes the output to the printing system. Add a percent before to disable this setting:

```
%o |lpr
```

Then the default output is a PostScript file.

Comment: perfecly works!!! Thank you so much!!! But there's one concern regarding the style, my title appeared extremely top of the paper.

Comment: @Herman This is a different question, an exercise to provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). :-)

Comment: I mean the texts starts from the top of the paper which is unusual.

Comment: @ Heiko, it works fine with dvips -o A.ps A.dvi but the output pdf is not in standard format (the title appears at the top of the page). I usually use latex A.tex----dvips A.dvi----psp2pdf A.ps----open A.pdf but I guess I delete unaware of in the hidden files related to terminal

Comment: @Herman: Use the right paper format for LaTeX (e.g. option for `\documentclass`) *and* the driver (e.g. `\usepackage[pass]{geometry}`).

Comment: where i can put the %o |lpr as the output goes to the printing system every time I run dvips filename.dvi. would it be possible to reinstall again?

Comment: @Herman: The configuration file for `dvips` is `config.ps`, see the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This one works fine without sending to the printer

```
dvips -Ppdf A.dvi -o A.ps ---> ps2pdf A.ps A.pdf---->open A.pdf
```