# auto-pst-pdf throws 'MiKTeX GPL Ghostscript 9.05: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1'

Tags: errors, miktex, auto-pst-pdf

In a machine with freshly installed MikTex 2.9 the below error is generated every time a file is compiled which uses `auto-pst-pdf` package, but then PDF is produced fine. Does this require any corrective actions?

```
Process started: pdflatex.exe --shell-escape -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "forestmwe".tex

Process started: pdflatex.exe --shell-escape -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "forestmwe".tex

This is dvips(k) 5.993 Copyright 2013 Radical Eye Software (www.radicaleye.com) ' TeX output 2014.06.23:1729' -> forestmwe-autopp.ps <d:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/dvips/base/tex.pro> <d:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/dvips/misc/alt-rule.pro> <d:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/dvips/pstricks/pstricks.pro> <d:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/dvips/pstricks/pst-algparser.pro> <d:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/dvips/pst-tools/pst-tools.pro> <d:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/dvips/pstricks/pst-dots.pro> <C:/Users/user0/AppData/Roaming/MiKTeX/2.9/dvips/pst-barcode/pst-barcode.pro> <d:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/enc/dvips/lm/lm-ec.enc> <d:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/dvips/base/texps.pro> <d:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/dvips/base/special.pro> <d:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/dvips/base/color.pro>.

<d:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmr5.pfb> <d:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmr10.pfb> <d:/Program Files (x86)/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmr8.pfb>[1] [1]

MiKTeX GPL Ghostscript 9.05: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1

Process exited normally
```

This answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/119295/37570 initially seemed similar but I could not find `lpr` in the `config.ps` file, so it did not apply.

Comment: Are you using tikz/pgf in the document? Which version?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Using Forest, which loads PFG. Latest everything as of today.

Comment: The current pgf doesn't work flawlessly together with auto-pst-pdf. There is an incompability with preview. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166623/tikz-and-auto-pst-pdf-break-ghostscript

Comment: Ok, that's clear. But is there any harm from the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use always

```
\usepackage[crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf}% With an onstalled Perl always crop=on!
\ifpdf
  \usepackage{forest}
\else
  \usepackage{pst-barcode}
\fi
```