# pst-optexp with MikTex on Windows

Tags: miktex, pstricks, windows, pst-optexp

I am trying to draw a diagram with `pst-optexp` in MikTex on Windows. Every time I try to compile using XeLatex, it would throw an error saying `MiKTeX GPL Ghostscript 9.19: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1`, so I tried the answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186255/auto-pst-pdf-throws-miktex-gpl-ghostscript-9-05-unrecoverable-error-exit-code) which did not resolve the issue. I tried using the advice [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119280/ghostscript-8-57-unrecoverable-error-exit-code-1/119295) but I could not find the file it referenced. Below is an example that demonstrates the issue. What can I do?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage[crop=off]{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{pst-optexp}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}
    \begin{optexp}
        \optbox[innerlabel, position=start](L)(End){$\ket{\psi_1}$}
        \beamsplitter[bssize=0.4, labelangle=-90](L)(L|C)(C){50/50 BS}
    \end{optexp}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: give a _complete_ and _short_ example, which shows your problem.

Comment: @Herbert updated with complete example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using node names, eg (L) but didn't define any with `\pnode`
Look into the documenation for an example or use coordinates:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-optexp}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-0.3,0)(2,3.7)
\psset{labeloffset=1, optboxwidth=1, arrowscale=1.5, arrowinset=0}
\optbox[position=end, labelangle=90](1,1)(1,2){Box}
\beamsplitter[labelangle=-90](1,2)(1,1)(2,1){BS}
\drawbeam[arrows=->]{1}{2}(2,1)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you show what this should look like? In the code you provided, there is no box around where the optbox should be and no beam appears.

Comment: see my answer to the other question.