# pst-solides3d display nothing and \psSolid command not found and GPL Ghostscript 9.50: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1

Tags: texlive, pst-solides3d

[image: pst-solides3d run failed]

here is my code.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{graphics}
\begin{document}
    \begin{pspicture}(-5,-4)(6,9)
        \psset{viewpoint=50 20 20 rtp2xyz, Decran=50}
        \psSolid[object=new,
        sommets=
        0 -2 0 
        -2 0 0 
        0 4 0 
        4 0 0 
        0 0 5, 
        faces={
            [3 2 1 0]
            [4 0 3]
            [4 3 2]
            [4 2 1]
            [4 1 0]},
        intersectiontype=0,
        intersectionplan={[0 0 1 -1] [0 0 1 -2]},
        intersectionlinewidth=1 2,
        intersectioncolor=(bleu) (rouge),
        plansepare={[0 0 1 -2]},
        name=firstSlice,
        action=draw]
    \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

The code runs absolutely well on other laptop, but doesn't in my laptop.It shows that my texstudio can't recognize the \psSolid command, and run out with the error "GPL Ghostscript 9.50: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1".I have no idea to deal with it, but I guess this is because my laptop is lack of some important files ?
However, what is interesting is that I can get my picture with the way mentioned in this link [Ghostscript 8.57: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119280/ghostscript-8-57-unrecoverable-error-exit-code-1)

So is anyone have the same problem or have the idea to handle it ?
*************************************************update in 2021.1.7*********
[image: platform warning]

here I find a warning in logs, and maybe I find the reason of this problem.There is not only windows os but also windows subsystem for linux in my laptop,so i think texlive is confusing to choose one platform to compile my code, that is just my guess, but any solution about this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX. SE. Apparently the LaTeX installation on the both laptops are not the same. For start try to upgrade your installation.

Comment: Nope, I copy the installation from another pc to mine, but it doesn't work

Comment: I'm not familiar with TeXlive, but coping of installation is not good idea. Better is make fresh installation after you remove old one.